# How can I decode a javascript snippet that is obfuscated with what appears to be a unicode or regex string with an eval() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, unicode, deobfuscation

So I came across an interesting piece of javascript that I can't quit figure out. It appears to me at first to be either regex function or a unicode string, that is then passed onto an eval function for processing. I have been trying for quite some time to decode it, but I don't seem to be making any headway. I'm hoping someone might be able to tell me what is going on here, and maybe show me how to decode it.

**Edit: So it turns out that the code I posted before was flawed from a previous decoding attempt. This is the corrected code.**

```
$(window).load(function() {
var d = '960';
var d1 = '960';
var q = 'u94';
var uw = $("#u94");
var _0xf924 = ["1m B=[\"\\a\\l\\v\\e\\k\\t\\d\\s\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\e\\9\\h\\g\\9\\i\\j\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\g\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\j\\9\\h\\h\\9\\i\\b\\9\\h\\e\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\i\\9\\h\\e\\9\\h\\k\\9\\b\\b\\l\\9\\k\\b\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\e\\9\\h\\g\\9\\i\\j\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\g\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\j\\9\\h\\h\\9\\i\\b\\9\\h\\e\\9\\k\\g\\9\\k\\j\\9\\h\\e\\9\\h\\k\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\g\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\f\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\k\\s\\m\\s\\9\\b\\g\\f\\9\\f\\j\\9\\a\\f\\9\\h\\b\\9\\a\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\h\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\f\\e\\9\\a\\e\\9\\h\\l\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\h\\f\\9\\f\\e\\9\\f\\e\\s\\m\\s\\9\\h\\a\\9\\h\\b\\9\\a\\k\\9\\f\\j\\9\\a\\j\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\j\\9\\f\\k\\s\\m\\s\\9\\b\\b\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\f\\i\\9\\a\\a\\s\\m\\s\\9\\h\\a\\9\\b\\j\\l\\9\\i\\i\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\h\\9\\f\\i\\9\\i\\j\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\g\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\j\\9\\h\\h\\9\\i\\b\\9\\k\\h\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\i\\9\\k\\h\\9\\h\\k\\9\\b\\b\\l\\9\\k\\b\\9\\h\\a\\9\\b\\j\\l\\9\\i\\i\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\h\\9\\f\\i\\9\\i\\j\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\g\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\j\\9\\h\\h\\9\\i\\b\\9\\k\\h\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\i\\9\\k\\h\\9\\h\\k\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\a\\s\\m\\s\\9\\f\\k\\9\\a\\f\\9\\a\\g\\9\\h\\f\\9\\a\\i\\s\\m\\s\\9\\f\\k\\9\\a\\f\\9\\f\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\f\\e\\9\\f\\j\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\g\\s\\m\\s\\9\\k\\g\\9\\k\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\i\\s\\m\\s\\s\\m\\s\\9\\k\\g\\9\\a\\i\\s\\m\\s\\9\\k\\b\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\j\\9\\f\\j\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\f\\9\\h\\f\\9\\a\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\b\\g\\e\\9\\a\\h\\9\\a\\h\\9\\b\\g\\e\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\j\\9\\f\\a\\9\\k\\g\\9\\a\\j\\9\\f\\e\\9\\f\\j\\9\\a\\h\\9\\f\\i\\9\\f\\e\\9\\a\\e\\9\\h\\g\\9\\a\\j\\9\\f\\a\\9\\k\\j\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\e\\9\\h\\b\\9\\a\\i\\9\\a\\g\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\f\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\a\\9\\b\\l\\g\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\f\\9\\f\\e\\9\\f\\e\\s\\m\\s\\9\\h\\l\\9\\a\\h\\9\\a\\a\\9\\b\\j\\g\\s\\m\\s\\9\\h\\a\\9\\h\\l\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\f\\9\\b\\j\\f\\9\\f\\j\\9\\a\\h\\9\\a\\e\\9\\f\\i\\9\\a\\g\\9\\h\\a\\9\\a\\f\\9\\h\\f\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\h\\g\\9\\a\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\i\\9\\a\\f\\9\\f\\e\\9\\b\\l\\g\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\f\\9\\f\\e\\9\\f\\e\\s\\m\\s\\9\\b\\g\\f\\s\\m\\s\\9\\f\\k\\9\\a\\e\\9\\f\\i\\9\\f\\a\\9\\k\\f\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\i\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\f\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\f\\s\\m\\s\\9\\f\\k\\9\\a\\f\\9\\b\\l\\l\\9\\f\\a\\9\\k\\f\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\i\\s\\m\\s\\9\\i\\i\\9\\f\\i\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\j\\9\\b\\b\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\f\\i\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\a\\s\\m\\s\\9\\f\\j\\9\\a\\f\\9\\h\\b\\9\\a\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\b\\g\\e\\9\\a\\h\\9\\a\\h\\9\\b\\g\\e\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\j\\9\\h\\a\\9\\h\\f\\9\\a\\h\\9\\f\\k\\9\\f\\a\\s\\m\\s\\9\\h\\a\\9\\h\\l\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\f\\9\\b\\j\\f\\9\\f\\j\\9\\a\\h\\9\\a\\e\\9\\f\\i\\9\\a\\g\\9\\h\\a\\9\\a\\f\\9\\h\\f\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\h\\g\\9\\a\\j\\9\\k\\b\\9\\b\\g\\f\\9\\f\\j\\9\\a\\f\\9\\h\\b\\9\\a\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\f\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\f\\9\\f\\a\\9\\a\\i\\9\\b\\b\\g\\9\\b\\l\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\i\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\e\\9\\h\\b\\9\\a\\i\\9\\a\\g\\s\\m\\s\\9\\f\\k\\9\\a\\e\\9\\f\\i\\9\\f\\a\\9\\a\\i\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\e\\9\\h\\b\\9\\a\\i\\9\\a\\g\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\h\\9\\i\\i\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\k\\9\\k\\j\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\e\\9\\h\\b\\9\\a\\i\\9\\a\\g\\s\\m\\s\\9\\f\\j\\9\\b\\l\\l\\s\\m\\s\\9\\f\\j\\9\\a\\f\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\e\\9\\f\\i\\9\\h\\b\\9\\f\\a\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\h\\9\\f\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\f\\j\\9\\a\\f\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\e\\9\\f\\i\\9\\h\\b\\9\\f\\a\\9\\h\\l\\9\\a\\h\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\h\\9\\f\\k\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\h\\9\\i\\i\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\k\\9\\b\\e\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\i\\s\\m\\s\\9\\k\\f\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\i\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\j\\9\\f\\k\\9\\a\\h\\9\\h\\g\\9\\a\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\h\\l\\9\\a\\h\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\k\\9\\f\\a\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\h\\9\\f\\j\\9\\f\\a\\9\\k\\f\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\i\\s\\m\\s\\9\\h\\l\\9\\a\\h\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\k\\9\\f\\a\\9\\h\\l\\9\\a\\h\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\h\\9\\f\\k\\9\\f\\a\\9\\k\\f\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\i\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\j\\9\\f\\e\\9\\a\\e\\9\\b\\l\\j\\9\\a\\j\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\j\\9\\f\\k\\9\\a\\h\\9\\h\\g\\9\\a\\j\\9\\b\\l\\k\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\k\\s\\m\\s\\9\\a\\j\\9\\a\\f\\9\\h\\f\\9\\a\\i\\s\\m\\s\\9\\h\\h\\9\\i\\j\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\g\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\j\\9\\h\\h\\9\\i\\b\\9\\h\\e\\9\\a\\k\\9\\a\\i\\9\\h\\e\\9\\h\\k\\9\\b\\b\\l\\9\\k\\b\\9\\a\\a\\9\\a\\e\\9\\h\\g\\9\\i\\j\\9\\a\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\g\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\j\\9\\h\\h\\9\\i\\b\\9\\h\\e\\9\\k\\g\\9\\k\\j\\9\\h\\e\\9\\h\\k\\s\\c\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\l\\a\\t\\x\\r\\e\\k\\d\\g\\c\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\j\\h\\t\\b\\l\\a\\d\\e\\k\\d\\j\\c\\c\\r\\e\\k\\d\\b\\c\\q\\u\\f\\h\\r\\X\\x\\r\\e\\k\\d\\l\\c\\q\\d\\g\\c\\q\\z\\b\\l\\h\\d\\e\\k\\d\\a\\c\\c\\r\\z\\s\\9\\h\\g\\9\\a\\e\\9\\f\\e\\9\\a\\e\\9\\h\\l\\9\\a\\e\\9\\f\\l\\9\\a\\e\\9\\a\\g\\9\\b\\j\\g\\s\\1f\\e\\k\\d\\e\\c\\A\\q\\A\\u\\x\\r\\e\\k\\d\\i\\c\\q\\d\\e\\k\\d\\h\\c\\c\\r\\e\\k\\d\\f\\c\\q\\d\\e\\k\\d\\j\\c\\c\\r\\e\\k\\d\\b\\c\\m\\b\\j\\h\\q\\u\\x\\r\\e\\k\\d\\e\\h\\c\\q\\d\\e\\k\\d\\e\\f\\c\\c\\r\\k\\k\\r\\q\\z\\a\\l\\v\\h\\j\\t\\d\\e\\k\\d\\k\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\g\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\b\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\j\\c\\c\\u\\a\\l\\v\\i\\g\\t\\x\\r\\b\\l\\f\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\i\\a\\t\\i\\g\\d\\h\\j\\d\\b\\c\\c\\r\\h\\j\\d\\g\\c\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\b\\k\\t\\i\\g\\d\\h\\j\\d\\b\\c\\c\\r\\h\\j\\d\\j\\c\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\g\\a\\t\\z\\A\\u\\b\\b\\k\\d\\h\\j\\d\\a\\c\\c\\r\\q\\d\\h\\j\\d\\e\\c\\c\\r\\k\\k\\r\\b\\b\\i\\q\\z\\b\\g\\a\\d\\b\\b\\i\\d\\h\\j\\d\\l\\c\\c\\r\\D\\d\\b\\e\\b\\S\\b\\l\\i\\c\\y\\D\\b\\j\\b\\q\\d\\g\\c\\c\\t\\b\\b\\i\\d\\h\\j\\d\\l\\c\\c\\r\\D\\d\\g\\S\\k\\c\\y\\D\\b\\j\\b\\q\\d\\g\\c\\A\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\f\\b\\t\\d\\e\\k\\d\\b\\l\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\e\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\a\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\f\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\h\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\i\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\c\\c\\u\\a\\l\\v\\h\\i\\t\\b\\g\\a\\d\\f\\b\\d\\g\\c\\c\\u\\f\\h\\r\\h\\i\\t\\t\\b\\e\\l\\q\\z\\h\\i\\t\\b\\g\\a\\d\\f\\b\\d\\b\\c\\c\\A\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\j\\e\\t\\f\\b\\d\\b\\c\\y\\h\\i\\y\\f\\b\\d\\j\\c\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\j\\a\\t\\f\\b\\d\\l\\c\\y\\h\\i\\y\\f\\b\\d\\j\\c\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\j\\j\\t\\b\\b\\k\\d\\f\\b\\d\\a\\c\\c\\r\\b\\j\\e\\m\\f\\b\\d\\j\\c\\q\\d\\f\\b\\d\\a\\c\\c\\r\\b\\j\\a\\m\\f\\b\\d\\j\\c\\q\\d\\f\\b\\d\\a\\c\\c\\r\\f\\b\\d\\e\\c\\m\\f\\b\\d\\j\\c\\q\\u\\i\\g\\d\\f\\b\\d\\h\\c\\c\\r\\f\\b\\d\\f\\c\\m\\b\\j\\j\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\g\\l\\t\\g\\u\\f\\h\\r\\h\\i\\t\\t\\f\\b\\d\\j\\c\\q\\z\\b\\g\\l\\t\\b\\A\\u\\a\\l\\v\\a\\b\\t\\d\\e\\k\\d\\b\\k\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\g\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\b\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\j\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\l\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\e\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\h\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\a\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\f\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\h\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\k\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\a\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\i\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\j\\k\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\l\\g\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\l\\b\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\l\\j\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\l\\l\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\a\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\l\\e\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\l\\a\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\l\\f\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\i\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\l\\h\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\l\\i\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\l\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\l\\k\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\e\\g\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\e\\b\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\e\\j\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\e\\l\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\e\\e\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\b\\c\\m\\e\\k\\d\\e\\a\\c\\c\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\b\\b\\t\\g\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\e\\j\\t\\g\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\b\\e\\t\\g\\u\\a\\l\\v\\k\\e\\t\\g\\u\\a\\l\\v\\k\\l\\t\\g\\u\\x\\r\\a\\b\\d\\j\\c\\q\\d\\a\\b\\d\\b\\c\\c\\r\\a\\b\\d\\g\\c\\q\\u\\k\\k\\v\\b\\b\\f\\r\\q\\z\\a\\l\\v\\e\\i\\t\\d\\a\\b\\d\\l\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\g\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\e\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\a\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\f\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\h\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\i\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\k\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\g\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\b\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\j\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\l\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\e\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\a\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\f\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\h\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\i\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\k\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\g\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\b\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\j\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\l\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\e\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\a\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\f\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\h\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\i\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\k\\c\\c\\u\\f\\h\\r\\x\\r\\e\\i\\d\\g\\c\\q\\d\\g\\c\\Q\\Q\\x\\r\\e\\i\\d\\l\\c\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\j\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\b\\c\\q\\q\\z\\a\\l\\v\\f\\f\\t\\x\\r\\e\\i\\d\\g\\c\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\a\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\e\\c\\y\\i\\a\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\l\\e\\t\\x\\r\\e\\i\\d\\g\\c\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\h\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\f\\c\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\i\\l\\t\\x\\r\\e\\i\\d\\g\\c\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\h\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\i\\c\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\i\\h\\t\\x\\r\\e\\i\\d\\g\\c\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\b\\g\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\k\\c\\q\\u\\f\\h\\r\\e\\i\\d\\b\\b\\c\\y\\i\\l\\y\\e\\i\\d\\b\\b\\c\\t\\t\\t\\e\\i\\d\\b\\j\\c\\q\\z\\i\\l\\t\\b\\l\\e\\A\\A\\b\\g\\i\\z\\a\\l\\v\\f\\f\\t\\i\\g\\u\\a\\l\\v\\i\\h\\t\\e\\i\\d\\b\\l\\c\\u\\a\\l\\v\\i\\l\\t\\b\\g\\j\\A\\u\\x\\r\\e\\i\\d\\b\\f\\c\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\b\\a\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\b\\e\\c\\y\\i\\k\\q\\u\\x\\r\\e\\i\\d\\g\\c\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\b\\g\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\b\\h\\c\\m\\e\\i\\d\\b\\c\\q\\u\\f\\h\\r\\b\\b\\b\\X\\t\\i\\h\\q\\z\\f\\f\\t\\x\\r\\e\\i\\d\\e\\c\\y\\i\\h\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\a\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\e\\c\\y\\i\\a\\q\\u\\f\\f\\d\\e\\i\\d\\b\\k\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\b\\i\\c\\m\\e\\i\\d\\b\\b\\c\\q\\u\\f\\f\\d\\e\\i\\d\\b\\k\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\j\\g\\c\\m\\e\\i\\d\\b\\b\\c\\q\\u\\b\\b\\e\\t\\f\\f\\d\\e\\i\\d\\j\\b\\c\\c\\r\\q\\u\\k\\e\\t\\f\\f\\d\\e\\i\\d\\b\\k\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\j\\e\\c\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\j\\l\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\j\\j\\c\\m\\e\\i\\d\\b\\b\\c\\q\\u\\k\\e\\t\\i\\f\\r\\k\\e\\q\\u\\k\\l\\t\\f\\f\\d\\e\\i\\d\\b\\k\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\j\\a\\c\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\j\\l\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\j\\j\\c\\m\\e\\i\\d\\b\\b\\c\\q\\u\\k\\l\\t\\i\\f\\r\\k\\l\\q\\u\\b\\b\\b\\t\\i\\h\\A\\u\\a\\l\\v\\i\\k\\t\\x\\r\\e\\i\\d\\j\\f\\c\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\b\\k\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\i\\c\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\j\\l\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\j\\j\\c\\m\\e\\i\\d\\b\\b\\c\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\i\\k\\t\\i\\f\\r\\i\\k\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\b\\h\\t\\f\\f\\d\\e\\i\\d\\j\\h\\c\\c\\r\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\g\\b\\t\\x\\r\\k\\i\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\j\\i\\c\\c\\r\\q\\u\\f\\h\\r\\X\\x\\r\\e\\i\\d\\l\\c\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\j\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\b\\c\\q\\q\\z\\x\\r\\e\\i\\d\\e\\c\\y\\i\\a\\q\\d\\e\\i\\d\\j\\k\\c\\c\\r\\q\\A\\u\\f\\h\\r\\b\\g\\b\\1g\\i\\l\\q\\z\\b\\b\\j\\t\\i\\l\\A\\b\\g\\i\\z\\b\\b\\j\\t\\b\\g\\j\\A\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\b\\a\\t\\r\\b\\b\\h\\D\\b\\g\\b\\q\\Y\\b\\b\\j\\u\\f\\h\\r\\b\\g\\b\\1d\\b\\g\\j\\Q\\Q\\i\\k\\t\\t\\b\\g\\j\\q\\z\\b\\b\\a\\t\\f\\f\\d\\e\\i\\d\\j\\i\\c\\c\\r\\q\\A\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\l\\b\\t\\b\\b\\e\\D\\b\\b\\a\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\g\\k\\t\\r\\b\\l\\b\\Y\\b\\b\\h\\q\\S\\r\\k\\e\\y\\k\\l\\q\\u\\f\\f\\d\\e\\i\\d\\b\\k\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\j\\g\\c\\m\\b\\g\\k\\y\\e\\i\\d\\j\\j\\c\\q\\u\\f\\f\\d\\e\\i\\d\\b\\k\\c\\c\\r\\e\\i\\d\\b\\i\\c\\m\\b\\g\\k\\y\\e\\i\\d\\j\\j\\c\\q\\A\\k\\k\\v\\b\\g\\h\\r\\q\\z\\a\\l\\v\\f\\g\\t\\d\\a\\b\\d\\l\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\a\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\f\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\i\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\l\\g\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\b\\k\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\l\\b\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\g\\c\\m\\a\\b\\d\\j\\j\\c\\c\\u\\f\\h\\r\\x\\r\\f\\g\\d\\g\\c\\q\\d\\g\\c\\q\\z\\a\\l\\v\\i\\e\\t\\x\\r\\f\\g\\d\\g\\c\\q\\d\\f\\g\\d\\j\\c\\c\\r\\f\\g\\d\\b\\c\\y\\i\\a\\q\\A\\b\\g\\i\\z\\a\\l\\v\\i\\e\\t\\x\\r\\f\\g\\d\\b\\c\\y\\i\\a\\q\\A\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\j\\i\\t\\x\\r\\k\\i\\q\\d\\f\\g\\d\\l\\c\\c\\r\\q\\u\\a\\l\\v\\k\\a\\t\\r\\b\\j\\i\\Y\\h\\i\\q\\D\\b\\g\\g\\u\\a\\l\\v\\b\\j\\k\\t\\i\\f\\r\\i\\e\\d\\f\\g\\d\\a\\c\\c\\r\\f\\g\\d\\e\\c\\q\\q\\y\\i\\f\\r\\i\\e\\d\\f\\g\\d\\a\\c\\c\\r\\f\\g\\d\\f\\c\\q\\q\\u\\k\\a\\t\\k\\a\\S\\b\\j\\k\\u\\i\\e\\d\\f\\g\\d\\a\\c\\c\\r\\f\\g\\d\\h\\c\\m\\k\\a\\y\\f\\g\\d\\i\\c\\q\\u\\i\\e\\d\\f\\g\\d\\a\\c\\c\\r\\f\\g\\d\\l\\c\\m\\k\\a\\y\\f\\g\\d\\i\\c\\q\\A\\f\\h\\r\\b\\g\\l\\t\\t\\b\\q\\z\\b\\b\\f\\r\\q\\u\\x\\r\\k\\i\\q\\d\\a\\b\\d\\l\\j\\c\\c\\r\\b\\b\\f\\q\\A\\u\\f\\h\\r\\b\\g\\l\\t\\t\\g\\q\\z\\b\\g\\h\\r\\q\\u\\x\\r\\k\\i\\q\\d\\a\\b\\d\\l\\j\\c\\c\\r\\b\\g\\h\\q\\A\\u\\i\\g\\d\\a\\b\\d\\l\\e\\c\\c\\r\\a\\b\\d\\l\\l\\c\\q\\A\\q\",\"\\n\",\"\\L\\13\\J\\K\\W\",\"\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\f\\n\\w\\g\\o\\E\\G\\g\\V\\n\\o\\h\\e\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\M\\n\\o\\f\\a\\n\\1s\\G\\11\\n\\o\\f\\k\\n\\o\\f\\e\\n\\o\\f\\b\\n\\o\\f\\1k\\n\\o\\f\\i\\n\\o\\h\\j\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\j\\j\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\k\\n\\o\\h\\g\\n\\o\\f\\19\\n\\o\\h\\l\\n\\o\\j\\N\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\h\\n\\K\\M\\n\\o\\f\\16\\n\\o\\f\\N\\n\\o\\h\\f\\n\\o\\f\\h\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\l\\n\\o\\f\\j\\n\\o\\j\\h\\n\\o\\j\\16\\n\\o\\f\\l\\n\\o\\j\\Z\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\G\\n\\o\\a\\N\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\e\\n\\o\\l\\N\\n\\o\\a\\1b\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\k\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\j\\l\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\a\\n\\13\\G\\11\\L\\p\\1l\\F\\W\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\G\\n\\o\\h\\a\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\V\\n\\o\\a\\j\\n\\o\\j\\g\\n\\o\\e\\i\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\e\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\l\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\j\\a\\n\\o\\h\\h\\n\\o\\j\\j\\n\\T\\K\\F\\E\\15\\T\\n\\M\\12\\F\\R\\W\\K\\15\\F\\n\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\E\\n\\E\\b\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\p\\n\\o\\a\\b\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\h\\n\\o\\j\\l\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\j\\b\\n\\p\\J\\L\\p\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\j\\g\\n\\o\\f\\f\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\g\\n\\E\\n\\o\\j\\19\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\j\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\p\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\a\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\R\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\i\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\f\\n\\o\\h\\k\\n\\1a\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\E\\n\\o\\e\\j\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\V\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\R\\n\\o\\f\\1b\\n\\1c\\F\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\j\\e\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\j\\f\\n\\o\\e\\l\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\M\\n\\o\\h\\Z\\n\\o\\h\\i\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\i\\n\\1c\\1p\\n\\W\\1o\\K\\L\\n\\12\\T\\n\\1n\\n\\o\\e\\b\\n\\o\\a\\h\\n\\Z\\n\\w\\g\\o\\h\\p\\p\\p\\o\\b\\b\\n\\F\\12\\J\\J\",\"\\11\\p\\13\\J\\G\\R\\p\",\"\",\"\\9\\T\\y\",\"\\9\\V\",\"\\1a\"];1q(U(P,1r,C,I,H,14){H=U(C){O C};18(!B[5][B[4]](/^/,1j)){17(C--){14[C]=I[C]||C};I=[U(H){O 14[H]}];H=U(){O B[6]};C=1};17(C--){18(I[C]){P=P[B[4]](1i 1h(B[7]+H(C)+B[7],B[8]),I[C])}};O P}(B[0],10,1e,B[3][B[2]](B[1]),0,{}))", "|", "split", "|||||||||x5C|x35|x31|x5D|x5B|x34|x36|x30|x37|x38|x32|x39|x33|x2C|x7C|x78|x65|x29|x28|x22|x3D|x3B|x20|x5F|x24|x2B|x7B|x7D|_0xaced|_0x985ex3|x2F|x64|x6E|x61|_0x985ex5|_0x985ex4|x6C|x69|x73|x66|x44|return|_0x985ex1|x26|x63|x2D|x77|function|x62|x74|x21|x2A|x41||x72|x75|x70|_0x985ex6|x6F|x45|while|if|x43|x67|x42|x71|x3E|144|x3A|x3C|RegExp|new|String|x46|x49|var|x7A|x68|x6D|eval|_0x985ex2|x76", "", "fromCharCode", "replace", "\\w+", "\\b", "g"];
eval(function(_0x4a22x1, _0x4a22x2, _0x4a22x3, _0x4a22x4, _0x4a22x5, _0x4a22x6) {
    _0x4a22x5 = function(_0x4a22x3) {
        return (_0x4a22x3 < _0x4a22x2 ? _0xf924[4] : _0x4a22x5(parseInt(_0x4a22x3 / _0x4a22x2))) + ((_0x4a22x3 = _0x4a22x3 % _0x4a22x2) > 35 ? String[_0xf924[5]](_0x4a22x3 + 29) : _0x4a22x3.toString(36))
    };
    if (!_0xf924[4][_0xf924[6]](/^/, String)) {
        while (_0x4a22x3--) {
            _0x4a22x6[_0x4a22x5(_0x4a22x3)] = _0x4a22x4[_0x4a22x3] || _0x4a22x5(_0x4a22x3)
        };
        _0x4a22x4 = [function(_0x4a22x5) {
            return _0x4a22x6[_0x4a22x5]
        }];
        _0x4a22x5 = function() {
            return _0xf924[7]
        };
        _0x4a22x3 = 1
    };
    while (_0x4a22x3--) {
        if (_0x4a22x4[_0x4a22x3]) {
            _0x4a22x1 = _0x4a22x1[_0xf924[6]](new RegExp(_0xf924[8] + _0x4a22x5(_0x4a22x3) + _0xf924[8], _0xf924[9]), _0x4a22x4[_0x4a22x3])
        }
    };
    return _0x4a22x1
}(_0xf924[0], 62, 91, _0xf924[3][_0xf924[2]](_0xf924[1]), 0, {}));
});
```

You can see at the second to last line here, we are passing '1m B=["\a\l....' to the function inside the eval. When I first saw this, I thought it was a Regex of some kind that was then converted by the browser as text, but to my knowledge, there isn't a way to convert it back? Looking into this further, I was told that it could all be unicode, but trying to convert the string back into characters has failed in ever converter I have tried. Am I way off base here?

**EDIT: See below for update! I exceeded the character limit, lol!**

Answer (score 1):

This line `var uw = $("#u94");` almost certainly means it's using content from the page itself to do the decoding.

The easiest way I can think of to *try* to get the code that is actually running is to return to where you found the code and open up your dev tools. Find the code again (I am guessing it's probably dynamically generated) and then without leaving the page copy/paste it into the text editor of your choice and do the following:

1) Change the first line like this

`$(window).load(function() {` -> `(function() {`

2) Change the last line like this:

`});` ->  `})()` (now you have a self-calling function)

3) Just before the last `return` add a `console.log`

The last `return` is returning the code that `eval` will actually run so add `console.log(_0x4a22x1)` before the `return` (again this exact variable name could be different upon returning to the page)

4) Copy/paste this into your dev tool console and if it worked it should print out the code that it's running.

**NOTE:** It's entirely possible that once the code runs the first time it removes the element (currently `#u94`) that contains something you need to run the code (so it could not work). So if it doesn't log the code out, then the first thing I would do it is a normal `View page source` (or `curl` the html) and find out what the `#u94` element contains and adapt the code as necessary.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably could have given more information, but it was really late, you know how it is. I actually know exactly what the code does. All it does is stretch an element vertically to fill a browsers vertical height responsively. That element is #94. In this case it wasn't so much about learning what the code does, as much as it was about learning how it does it, aka, how does: 1m B=["\a\l\v\e\k\t\d\s\9\a\a\9....... translate to a function... I didn't think about logging that last return, I will try that and report back!